Heads Or tails can't choose from random option (Python)
i wanted a build a heads and tails game , but when i allocate the values of heads -0 and tails -1
then even if i choose tails and the random function results comes , but it doesn't match mine .
like if i select heads then if the random function also choose heads then it should come as yay you win but it coming the opposite.
import random

choice = input("Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? ").lower()
if choice == "yes":
    head_or_tails = input("Choose Heads or Tails -- ").lower()
    random_number = random.randint(1,2)
    print(random_number)
    if random_number == 1:
        if head_or_tails == "heads":
            print("Yay! You won , It's Heads")
        if head_or_tails == 'tails':
            print("Sorry the Computer won, It's Tails, Better Luck Next Time")
    if random_number == 2:
        if head_or_tails == "tails":
             print("Yay! You won, It's Tails")
        if head_or_tails == 'heads':
             print("Sorry the Computer won, It's Heads, Better Luck Next Time")
if choice == "no":
    print("It's Okay You can play Next Time" )


Please [edit] your question to include a session showing the actual (wrong) output, together with the input you give. Copy-paste it as text.

Flagging as "typo"; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78910541

First of all share the output you are getting and in in your attempt you've mentioned assigning values to head/tails with 0/1 & in the program used 1/2 .
And the Solution is to interchange the 2nd print() section of each if conditions.
Snippet-
if random_number == 1:
    if head_or_tails == "heads":
        print("Yay! You won , It's Heads")
    if head_or_tails == 'tails':
        print("Sorry the Computer won, It's Heads, Better Luck Next Time")
if random_number == 2:
    if head_or_tails == "tails":
         print("Yay! You won, It's Tails")
    if head_or_tails == 'heads':
         print("Sorry the Computer won, It's Tails, Better Luck Next Time")-


Your issue deals with how you are comparing the coin face and the user choice. There is a better way to do it that does not require you to translate int to str. You could simply use random.choice and compare str to str. You have another issue. You are not checking the user input to make sure that it is a valid choice.
You don't have to be so verbose with your vars. You have a couple of choices and a coin face. In this case the first choice can expire as soon as we know what it is, and the second choice can reuse the variable to store the new choice. heads_or_tails isn't a good name, because it's not specific to which instance of "heads" or "tails" you are referring to. Is it the user or the coin? face is a better name because only the coin has faces, and this var is referring directly to the coin. coin, toss, or side would also be acceptable.
import random

CHOICES = 'yes', 'no'
FACES = 'heads', 'tails'

def unacceptable(choice:str, options:tuple) -> bool:
    if wrong := (choice not in options):
        print(f"Please enter a valid response. ({', '.join(options)})")
    
    return wrong
    
while True:
    choice = input("Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? ").lower()
   
    if unacceptable(choice, CHOICES):
        continue
        
    if choice == "yes":
        while True:
            choice = input("Choose Heads or Tails: ").lower()
            
            if unacceptable(choice, FACES):
                continue

            break
            
        face = random.choice(FACES)
    
        print(f"The coin flip result is: {face.capitalize()}")

        if choice == face:
            print("Yay! You won!")
        else:
            print("Sorry, you lost. Better luck next time.")
    else:
        print("It's okay, you can play next time.")
        break


The OP hasn't edited their post at all

@MatBailie: I don't think any edits within the first 5 minutes show up in the edit history.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk This answer was an hour after the question was posted and the edit to the answer was along time after that. So when the answer had "Edit: You changed your post, a lot. You even changed the printed messages. You were checking that "yes" or "no" wasn't something else." it made no sense.

@MatBailie: I don't know what happened, I'm just reminding you that edits within the 1st 5 minutes are not recorded. Sometimes people start answering a question and then get distracted, only to return a while later. I don't know what actually happened.

@MatBailie - I don't even understand why any of this matters. My answer was an hour after because I got a phone call while I was writing it. My edit was a long time after that because a long time after that I realized the question had different print statements, and was missing the print that said "Please use a valid response". This isn't a Scooby Doo mystery.

I responded to a phrase you edited into your own answer. Edit: You changed your post, a lot Which is objectively not the case.


like if i select heads then if the random function also choose heads
then it should come as yay you win but it coming the opposite.


We need to clean up the code. We are able to reduce nested if/else.
The index one or two are not necessary.
We will be using Walrus (Python 3.8). Walrus Operator allows you to
assign a value to a variable within an expression. This can be useful
when you need to use a value multiple times in a loop, but don’t want
to repeat.
Use f-string and r-string

Snippet:
import random

outcomes = ["Heads", "Tails"]

if (player_choice := input("Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? ").lower())== "yes":
 
    head_or_tails = input("Choose Heads or Tails -- ").lower()
    random_number = random.choice(outcomes)
     
    if player_choice.lower() == random_number.lower():
        print(r"Yay! You won , It's Heads")
    else:
        print(f"Sorry the Computer won, It's {random_number}, Better Luck Next Time")
        
if player_choice == "no":
    print(r"It's Okay You can play Next Time")

Output:
Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? Yes
Choose Heads or Tails -- Heads
Sorry the Computer won, It's Tails, Better Luck Next Time


Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? No
It's Okay You can play Next Time


Your bug is that you're printing the wrong messages...
import random

choice = input("Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? ").lower()
if choice == "yes":
    head_or_tails = input("Choose Heads or Tails -- ").lower()
    random_number = random.randint(1,2)
    print(random_number)

    # BOTH messages should says "it's heads" 
    if random_number == 1:
        if head_or_tails == "heads":
            print("Yay! You won , It's Heads")
        if head_or_tails == 'tails':
            print("Sorry the Computer won, It's Tails, Better Luck Next Time")
            #                                   ^^^^^ wrong

    # BOTH messages should says "it's tails" 
    if random_number == 2:
        if head_or_tails == "tails":
            print("Yay! You won, It's Tails")
        if head_or_tails == 'heads':
            print("Sorry the Computer won, It's Heads, Better Luck Next Time")
            #                                   ^^^^^ wrong

if choice == "no":
    print("It's Okay You can play Next Time" )

I'd change it to...
import random

choice = input("Would You like to play Heads or Tails game? ").lower()
if choice == "yes":
    guess = input("Choose Heads or Tails -- ").capitalize()
    coin  = random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])
    print(coin)

    if guess == coin:
        print(f"Yay! You won, It's {coin}.")
    else:
        print(f"Sorry the Computer won, It's {coin}, Better Luck Next Time")

if choice == "no":
    print("It's Okay You can play Next Time" )


@PresidentJamesK.Polk - why must it be a revenge downvote? Revenge from who? This answer isn't that great. It's just a bunch of code.

@OysterShucker yup, just a bunch of code. Other than the explanation of the bug, and comments in the code highlighting the exact locations.

The first code block doesn't fix anything, read it again. It simply shows the bug, which is valuable. The OP clearly needs pointing to their actual mistake, just as much as any refactoring.
